# Why is this method have to be a callback method

Tags: java, android, callback

I have never understood the concept of callback functions properly. Now I am studying java and android programming. and I have encountered this method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
}
```

From my understanding of normal methods, inside the implementation of this method, this method is calling itself, so the implementation will start again and it will call itself again, and so on... which results in an infinite loop of calling and starting implementation of this method.

Can somebody suggest me some document/tutorial etc. which is short and easy, and which explains what callback methods are and what is the flow of their execution.

OR

Can somebody tell me in a simple way the flow of execution of the implementation of this method onCreate() and why is the call to the method itself needed and what this call actually does.

Please reply ASAP, I'll be grateful, since I have my work dependent on this concept.

Answer (score 3):

No, it will not end in an infinite loop, because you call the `onCreate` method of the super class `super.onCreate()`.

If you would call `this.onCreate()` you will also not end in an infinite loop. You will get a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

The callback methods are invoked by the android runtime and allows you to hook in the lifecycle of an `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Will execute the code in the `onCreate` method of the `Activity` class (you're currently in a subclass of `Activity`, thus `Activity` is your super class). You're doing this to setup some basic functionality that is already defined there.

This has nothing to do with callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't call itself. It calls `super.onCreate()`, which thus invokes the `onCreate()` method of its superclass.

Answer (score 1):

The call `super.onCreate()' calls the method onCreate in the superclass of the current class.  If X extends Y, then in a method in X, super.onCreate() calls onCreate() in Y.  After onCreate() in Y finishes executing, execution will resume with the line after super.onCreate() in X.

Callback methods are a different issue.  You use callback methods when you want code that you write called by a framework of some sort (such as Android), often on the occurrence of some event.  In this case, when whatever it is that is referenced gets created, it calls code of yours -- that gives your code a chance to do things that are specific to your application.  Usually it is difficult to know when things like this are going to happen, especially in a GUI environment like Android, and so callbacks become a common way of handling this situation.